Passing customized UUID to a task
I'm working with the python-huey 2.5.1 in a Python application and need to set custom task IDs for each task, rather than using the automatically generated uuid4 provided by Huey. I see in the docs there is one attribute called id in the Task instance https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#Task. TaskWrapper instance also has one method s() to create a task instance but I don't see there is one argument https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#TaskWrapper.s that allows users to pass customized uuid.
from huey import RedisHuey

# Create a huey instance.
huey = RedisHuey('my-app')

@huey.task()
def add_numbers(a, b):
    return a + b

#generate customized uuid
task_id = generate_customized_id()

#I want to set task_id as the id of task instance
 
result = add_number(1, 2)
#below is task id auto generated by huey
id = result.id

